# How can an Eclipse plugin access the project directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, workspace

Is there a way to get the directory of a project in Eclipse?  We are writing a plugin that will allow the user to select files, and then run some processes on those files.  I would ideally like to be able to get all the files with a certain extension, but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sure:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()
```

will get you a list of all the projects in the workspace.  you can easily iterate to find the one you want.  At that point, you can look for certain files by extensions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable your users to select files inside eclipse workspace with a certain extension, you can look at the class **org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ElementTreeSelectionDialog** (org.eclipse.ui.dialogs plugin)as a start.

Then, to have an example on how to make it filter extensions, you can look at the class **org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.FilteredElementTreeSelectionDialog** (org.eclipse.jdt.ui plugin) to see how they do it and then reimplement the stuff.

This should give you a higher level of action than going threw files inside projects by hand and reimplement dialogs.