# Access project directory from eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

This is a question already asked by someone:

[How can an Eclipse plugin access the project directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242032/eclipse-project-directory)

The answer was good: using `ResourcesPlugin`.

But for some reason, under no circumstances will my Ganymede eclipse recognise the existence of `org.eclipse.core.resources` package which contains `ResourcesPlugin`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually something to do with the Manifest:

- is the package imported (`Import-Package`), or the bundle required (`Require-Bundle`) in your plugin.
- (sanity check) is the package exported by the source bundle (`Export-Bundle`).

If both of these check out, then I would look at the target platform. A typical base install for RCP only does not include the `resources` bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Add the bundle **`org.eclipse.core.resources`** in your plugin dependencies. That should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

(*) You might have specified a version constraint in the Manifest.MF for the dependency. And the available version is different. If so, remove the constraint or just click the Match in the Properties of the depedency

(*) Check your target platform and verify whether this org.eclipse.core.resources plugin exists

(*) If the error still persist, go to the Plug-ins tab in the launch configuration of your RCP. Check whether the o.e.c.resources is added. The Validate Plug-ins buttons should be helpful to determine any issues